# Avoid image decompression blocking the main thread

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, javax.imageio

I have some code to display an animated GIF image using a UIImageView, here: https://github.com/amleszk/GifBlocking

It works well for 99% of cases, although there is an issue with a certain type of GIF image, An example can be found here: http://i.imgur.com/mbImw.gif

This gif receives 101 images fine, then blocks the main thread when it comes time to display the UIImageView containing the animated images. Its fine to decompress the gif if it has compression, but how would i stop this blocking the main thread?

The methods that get invoked on the main thread are 
`DGifDecompressInput` 
`DGifDecompressLine` 
`copyImageBlockSetGIF`

the problem is the gif decompression happens when the view gets added to the heirarchy - which should be done on the main thread

Thanks

Comment: *"some code similar to ..."* is pretty vague. It is difficult to help without the seeing the exact code.

Comment: Added a git repo to reproduce here: https://github.com/amleszk/GifBlocking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

grasGendarme's code is useful, but note that UIImage is lazy and won't decode the image until it is really needed. The key is that you have to force decompression on a background thread using `CGContextDrawImage`. So use [UIImage+JTImageDecode.h](https://gist.github.com/mystcolor/1257111) to create an uncompressed image version on the background, then set it back to the main thread.

Comment: Works well (the downside is the image is rendered twice?), the git repo has been updated with an example.

Comment: Rendering means generating an image from formatted data. Here, the image is rendered (decompressed) once, then kept on the UIImage object, and dumped on video memory later. Whether you do it in two steps or one, the image will only be rendered once.

Comment: I tried this and my supposedly animated UIimage is no longer animated, it just shows the first frame - anything else I'm overlooking?

Comment: This won't work with animated images since it is drawing one frame. Use https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif/ which is already extracting (and decompressing) the images with CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex.

Answer (score 2):

It would be great to see the actual code. Without that, our help is limited.

Maybe you can put a line:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(yourBlockingMethod:) withObject:yourObject];
```

Or modify your library to decompress the GIF on a background thread, then use `setNeedsDisplay` on the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

You could make everything happen on a separate thread using Grand Central Dispatch and serial queues:

```
// create the queue that will process your data:
dispatch_queue_t dataProcessQueue = dispatch_queue_create("data process queue", NULL); // the name is there for debugging purposes
    //dispatch to the newly created queue, and do not wait for it to complete
    dispatch_async(dataProcessQueue, ^{
        // load and decode gif
        // ...
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // put gif in place (UI work always happen on the main queue)
            // ...
    });
});
```